# Low-Pass filter on AVcc pin for ATtiny

Tags: avr, atmega, attiny, low-pass

The datasheet for the ATtiny861a states that "If the ADC is used AVCC should be connected to VCC through a low-pass filter". The datasheet doesn't specify what values I should use or what style of low-pass filter I should use. The ATMega datasheets on the otherhand state that the low-pass filter should be a 10uH inductor connecting AVcc to Vcc with a 100nF capacitor connected to ground. Is this the same style of low-pass filter I should be using for my ATtiny or is there something better?

Comment: What frequencies will the parts of your system be running at?

Comment: The clock speed will be ~8Mhz

Comment: The only ADC inputs are from a KXTC9-4100 accelerometer

http://www.kionix.com/sites/default/files/KXTF9-4100%20Specifications%20Rev%206.pdf

Comment: the 10uH and 100nF LC filter is about 160Khz cut-off frequency. Seems reasonable to reduce clock and RF noise. Use a little ferrite bead and a little SMD cap, should be easy!

Answer (score 4):

I think the ATmega advice is pretty good.  With L1 = 10uH and C1 = 100nF, the 8MHz processor frequency is down over 60dB.  I added a series resistor R2 = 10Ω to reduce the resonant peak of the LC pair.  It may be not necessary, though.

### Circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0GPRg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Frequency response

[image: Frequency response]